# Image of a Borel measure by a local homeomorphism

Tags: measure-theory

To simplify matters we assume all topological spaces have countable bases.
Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, $\mathcal B(X)$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the set of open subsets. A Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$ is a measure defined on $\mathcal B(X)$ such that $\mu(K) \lt \infty$ for every compact subset $K$.

Let $\psi: X \rightarrow Y$ be a surjective local homeomorphism where $X$ and $Y$ are locally compact Hausdorff spaces. Let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $X$.

> Is there a unique Borel measure $\nu$ on $Y$ such that $\nu(\psi(M)) = \mu(M)$ whenever $M \in \mathcal B(X)$ and $\psi$ is one to one on $M$.
>
> If the assertion is negative, what conditions should we add to make it affirmative?

The motivation is that the assertion seems to be affirmative if $X = G$ is a locally compact Hausdorff group and $\mu$ is the Haar measure on $G$ and $Y = G/N$ where $N$ is a discrete normal subgroup and $\psi$ is the canonical homomorphism.

Comment: $\nu$ would be the pushforward of $\mu$ under $\psi$, right?

Comment: @pizza What do you mean by the pushforward? In any case, I think the question is clearly stated.

Comment: [Pushforward measure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure)

Comment: @pizza I don't think so. In any case, I think the question is clearly stated. Is there anything you don't understand about it?